# python : UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 2201: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: python, encoding

I'm getting `UnicodeDecodeError` in the following code:

```
cr.execute(" SELECT c.nouveau_champs AS nouveau_champs FROM parametrage_consultation c ORDER BY c.order " )
nom = cr.fetchall() #un tuple d'elements
cr.execute(" SELECT c.type AS type FROM parametrage_consultation c ORDER BY c.order" )
type = cr.fetchall()
for i in range(len(nom)):
    nom_str=''.join(nom[i])
    type_str=''.join(type[i])
    result = file("E:/addons/consultation/consultation_temp.py","r").read().replace("        #put a new field here","         '"+nom_str+"': fields."+type_str+"('"+nom_str+"'),\n         #put a new field here\n")
    file("E:/addons/consultation/consultation_temp.py","w").write(result)
    result1 = file("E:/addons/consultation/consultation_view_new.txt","r").read().encode("utf-8").replace("             <!--put a new field here-->",'             <field name="'+nom_str+'"/>\n             <!--put a new field here-->')
    file("E:/addons/consultation/consultation_view_new.txt","w").write(result1)
```

The problem is that i'm getting a `UnicodeDecodeError` while reading the second `.txt` file.

Comment: result1 = file("E:/addons/consultation/consultation_view_new.txt","r").read().replace("             <!--put a new field here-->",'             <field name="'+nom_str+'"/>\n             <!--put a new field here-->')

Comment: You can [edit] your question to add more information.

Comment: @AsmaaMh: Please include the full traceback of your error in your question. You probably have a unicode value in `nom_str`, can you please give us the exact value for it (use `print repr(nom_str)` to produce a Python literal expression).

Comment: nom is python tuple   : for i in range(len(nom)):
                                                nom_str=''.join(nom[i])

Comment: Try editing your question @AsmaaMh, include your code and other details there.

Comment: Improved code formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Your file uses a character encoding different from the one expected by Python. You can specify the encoding explicitly by using `codecs.open` instead of `open`.

See https://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html

Comment: Rather than `codecs.open()`, use `io.open()`. The older `codecs` implementation has some serious limitations and issues no longer present in the newer `io` library, which is the default I/O framework for Python 3.